# Get timezones based on zipcode

Tags: timezone, zipcode

I want to get the current time based on my input zipcode in php.

E.g. If i will enter 71020 then I want the accurate time of that location.

Is there any web service exists to which I can make a call by sending parameter as zipcode.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First use a service that will give you the latitude and longitude on a zip code.  There are many, but an easy one is [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeSearch).  If you search here on StackOverflow or Google, you will find plenty of others.

Then take a look at the [many different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824) you can resolve a time zone from a latitude and longitude.

Comment: Thanks. This will be a 2 way process. Is there any direct approach so that by giving the zip-code as parameter , I can get the time details of that particular location?

Comment: The problem is that there are some zip codes that do not refer to physical locations, or can span multiple time zones.  So they are rarely paired together directly.  When you ask for the lat/lon of a zip code, it is an approximation.  When you ask for the time zone of a lat/lon, it is much more precise.  You may find some database that has both, but I don't have a direct example of one.  If it has both, then the approximation is baked in to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about web services but maxmind has databases you can buy to do ip lookups